# Wordpress get_prev & get_next not working

Tags: wordpress, navigation, posts

I can't understand why my code is not working:

```
<?php 
function get_prev_next_links(){
    echo '<div class="post-nav">';
    $prev_post = get_previous_post();
    if ( !empty( $prev_post ) );
    echo '<div class="prev-post">';
    echo '<a href="'get_permalink( $prev_post->ID )'">&lsaquo; Previous ('echo $prev_post->post_title')</a>';
    echo '</div>';
    endif;

    $next_post = get_next_post();

    if ( !empty( $next_post ) );
    echo '<div class="next-post">';
    echo '<a href="'get_permalink( $next_post->ID )'">Next ('echo $next_post->post_title') &rsaquo;</a>';
    echo '</div>';
    endif;

    echo '</div>';
}
add_shortcode ( 'the_prev_next_links' , 'get_prev_next_links' );
?>
```

I pasted this code into my functions.php file, so that I can use the shortcode [the_prev_next_links] to call the function. But it just gives me the 'whitescreen'. So there must be something missing in my above code, or something that I've got wrong.

Note: this is outside the loop.
Any pointers?
Thanks :-)

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working' - do you get errors?  What results do you get, and what did you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably in your `if` syntax.  You're ending the if statements with semicolons like this:

```
if ( !empty( $next_post ) );
```

The should have colons, like this:

```
if ( !empty( $next_post ) ):
```

Here's the PHP reference on the "alternate syntax" for control structures:  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Personally, I prefer to use braces to wrap code blocks, but this is valid too.  Most editors will highlight brace pairs, which can help while editing and debugging.

You also need to concatenate your strings properly.  This is incorrect:

```
echo '<a href="'get_permalink( $prev_post->ID )'">&lsaquo; Previous ('echo $prev_post->post_title')</a>';
```

This will work:

```
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ) . '">&lsaquo; Previous (' . $prev_post->post_title . ')</a>';
```

Comment: Ahh yes... thanks for this. I tried this as well  - but still not working unfortunately

Comment: White screens are very frustrating.  Try getting error_reporting() to work:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php.  Error messages are better than guesswork any day.

Comment: Thanks Surreal - this part I missed.

Answer (score 0):

You do have a lot of syntax errors which makes this question off-topic actually. You should set debug to true and work through all of them. These errors are quite explicit so you will be able to fix them quickly. Also, get yourself a proper synatx highligher.

On your use of `:` and `endif`, don't do that. This goes for `endwhile`, `endforeach`. Also, don't make use of the following synatx

```
if( x == y)
 Do something
```

These are all valid php, but it makes is very hard to debug, and neither is it supported by most syntax highlighters. Make use of curly brackets (`{}`) instead. It makes debugging later so much easier, and this also eliminate silly syntax error like `;` instead of `:`

Just one BIG note here, when all your syntax errors is sorted, make sure to add `global $post;` at the start inside your function, otherwise your paging won't work